# IOS BLE packet loss

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm writing an IOS/iPhone app that communicates with an sp-10c imu via bluetooth low energy. The packets I am receiving were originally 61 bytes long, but I have shortened them to 38 bytes so that the packet is sent in the minimum number of notifications.

I have no control over the actual programming of the sp-10c, but they do give me control of some of the settings. I can change what all info I receive (accelerations, gyros quaternions, etc) and thereby change the packet size, and I can also change the transmission interval (by 10 millisecond intervals). I have read a lot of the questions and answers on here related to this subject, but the only solutions I have seen require having programming control over the peripheral device, which I do not have.

I have also read Apple's handbook on this, which states that the minimum interval should be 20 ms. If I could reliably get entire packets at 50 hz, that would work for my needs. Anything less is pretty much worthless. My problem is that I'm getting intervals of massive packet loss at the 20ms interval (there are times when 40 or more packets are lost, and this happens regularly). I really don't see reliable results until I slow it down to an interval of 60 ms or more, which, as I said, is worthless. (I am trying to sense a sharp change in acceleration that lasts about 20 - 40ms)

Most of the questions and answers on here are somewhat dated, but I saw where someone said that things may have gotten worse as far as the BLE connection + Apple devices go. It has been suggested that classic bluetooth is the only way to go when large amounts of throughput are needed, but the sp-10c does not offer classic bluetooth as an option.

My questions are:

Is this the normal behavior for a ble connection with apple devices?

Has anyone had any success getting reliable ble notifications at 20ms with    longer packets?

Should I give up now and try to find an imu with classic bluetooth?

I guess what I'm really getting at is this: Am I doing something wrong, or is this just par for the ble/iPhone course?

Would it help to try and limit the packet to less than 20 bytes so it is received in one notification?

Comment: Anybody in the late crowd have any ideas?

Comment: In the iOS side, if you want to write a value your have the choice (if available on the other side) to `ZzZwriteWithReponse` or `ZzZwriteWithoutResponse` If you `ZzZwriteWithResponse` it should work, since if it fails, it may do it again. Does your device implement that kind of thing?

Comment: No, It implements WriteWithoutRespnse because it is supposed to be faster.